# Lenovo W541 at Ubuntu 22.04 occures micro delays

Tags: mouse, 22.04, lenovo, freeze

My **Lenovo W541**, driven by **Ubuntu 22.04.1**, make constantly micro interrupts/delays.
It shows up when:

1. you watch videos (notwithstanding at which resolution): video stops for a couple of milliseconds about once a 1-2 seconds, like if I had a slow old GPU
2. you type text (in any text editor or even in the address bar in the browser). You type, for example, "hello" but the OS freezes for a millisecond and you see "**helllllllllllllllllo**" like if you keep pushing "**l**" letter for a long time.
3. when you are just moving your mouse all across the screen and you see how it stops for a small periods every 1 second or even faster. It looks like the cursor is on the glued surface and clings for a short moment here and there.
4. when you open/close window/app/tab_in_app it can freeze for up to 1 sec (freezer the screen with mouse).
5. Machine can freeze completely so the only reboot is the only remedy.

Interesting thing, that music from Youtube.Music does not stop when the machine freezes, even if the machine freezes totally and I have to reboot it bruteforcely.

My Lenovo has the hardware as below:
[image]
[image]

`free` shows this:
[image]

I have SSD HDD and I have a side OS Windows 10 Pro, which has NO of the listed above problems with the same machine (incl. HDD).

Please, help!

Thank you!

Comment: You should look at system log for recurring error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the video driver to 418 nVidia (proprietary) (rebooted), re-enabled a Nouveau driver (rebooted again) and everything got well now!